# Check if Jython object implements Java interface

Tags: jython

How can I check if a Jython object implements a Java interface?

Example: Jython's `dict` is really [`PyDictionary`](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/core/PyDictionary.html) which implements the [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface. If I use `isinstance()`, it simply reports `False`:

```
>>> from java.util import Map
>>> from org.python.core import PyDictionary
>>> isinstance({}, Map)
False
>>> isinstance(PyDictionary(), Map)
False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check to see if an object implements an interface by using [`Class.isInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29) (an *interface* is an instance of `Class`):

```
>>> from java.util import Map
>>> from org.python.core import PyDictionary
>>> Map.isInstance({})
True
>>> Map.isInstance(PyDictionary())
True
```